# How to set alignment in excel file which is exported by crystal report

Tags: excel, vb.net, insert, alignment, crystal-reports-2008

How to set alignment in excel file which is exported by crystal report vb.net.

I want to add data into the excel file through Crystal report vb.net

Answer (score 0):

Select all DATA> Text to Columns and split according to ur need, then finish